# Button disable after clicking issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a submit button in my login page. I want to disable the submit button after clicking once.I'ts working fine with `this.disabled = true;` query and after disable the button it's going to the next page. The problem is that when I press back button it's still is disable because the page is not reloaded from server,It's loading from the local cache. I want to enable the button every time when I come back to the login page. I can clear the cache but there is some problem like if it will load from the server and project will be slow. What will be the best way to do this?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','button',function(){
        this.disabled = true
        window.location="https://www.google.co.in/"
    })
})
</script>
<body>
<button type="submit" id="button">Click Me!</button> 
</body>
```

Comment: why do you need to disable it if it goes to another page?

Comment: @Sergio -- Probably to avoid multiple form submissions or something to that extent.

Comment: @sbeliv01, yes possible. Just curious to understand better OP's idea.

Comment: @Sergio here my example is simple so you can feel that its not required but for form submission or ajax POST it is required otherwise it will send multiple request.

Comment: Do you get the url from ajax call? can you not enable it on the response function of the ajax?

Comment: can you please provide some code so that i can relise how it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set the buttons initial disabled attribute to disabled in the body html to prove that the code does enable it again (so you can remove that in the body)
I hope this helps:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#button").removeAttr('disabled');
$("#button").click(function(){
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        window.location="https://www.google.co.in/"
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<button type="submit" id="button" disabled="disabled">Click Me!</button> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need another event that ensures the button is enabled on page load. Kind of like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").disabled = false;
    $(document).on('click','button',function(){
        this.disabled = true
        window.location="https://www.google.co.in/"
    })
})
</script>
<body>
<button type="submit" id="button">Click Me!</button> 
</body>
```

I didn't try running this so I'm not sure if the syntax is 100% but it should give you  the right idea.

Comment: This will disable the button, and then on click enable it.

Comment: No. The disable is set to true inside the onclick listener. Document.ready() is called after rendering the page. This code enables the button after page render. Granted I'm not sure if .ready() will be called if loaded in from cache.

Comment: dude you should read the question carefully.button enable will work when it will fire $("#button").disabled = false; on click back button will not fire any query it will return the page from cache

Comment: I did read it carefully. I assumed the web browser would call .ready() after rendering the page from cache. I may be mistaken though. There should be an event that is triggered upon rendering though. There is always an event.